# Node.js Express.js | Automatically render handelbar templates from views/static folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have got the following code to automatically load my handelbar templates from the views/static folder without having to manually setup a route for each page.

```
app.get("/:template", function(req,res){
    var template = req.params.template; // Is this safe?
    res.render("static/" + template, function(err, html) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(404, 'Sorry cant find that!');
        } else {
            res.send(html);
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine, however I am worried that this potentially exposes my app to security problems. Any suggestions how I could do this better. I am using Express. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty safe.

Usually, you have to worry about paths being passed that contain stuff like `../` (to go back a directory level), but those won't match your route. Also, the route you declare will stop matching at a `/`, so requests like `/foo/../bar` won't match either.

An issue that *may* occur is when the `static` directory contains files that you don't want to expose: a request for `/secret.js` will at least *try* to render a file called `static/secret.js`.